# What causes this "Spawning child process: Exec format error"?

Tags: microsoft-windows, files

Sometimes when I try to open a file, I get this error. It can be any file type (`.org`, `.html`, etc.) Once Emacs gets into the state, it seems to stay messed up, and I have to restart.

Emacs version: GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2023-08-02
OS: Windows 11 Home

I called `toggle-debug-on-error`, and the trace of the error is shown below.

Note: the `magit` command has sometimes worked, and `git` works from command line, so it's not like the `git.exe` is corrupted.

Is there a way to fix this, or a way to get more information that might reveal the problem?

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Spawning child process" "Exec format error")
  call-process("C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe" nil (t nil) nil "--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" "-c" "log.showSignature=false" "-c" "color.ui=false" "-c" "color.diff=false" "-c" "i18n.logOutputEncoding=UTF-8" "rev-parse" "--show-toplevel")
  process-file("C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe" nil (t nil) nil "--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" "-c" "log.showSignature=false" "-c" "color.ui=false" "-c" "color.diff=false" "-c" "i18n.logOutputEncoding=UTF-8" "rev-parse" "--show-toplevel")
  apply(process-file "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe" nil (t nil) nil ("--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" "-c" "log.showSignature=false" "-c" "color.ui=false" "-c" "color.diff=false" "-c" "i18n.logOutputEncoding=UTF-8" "rev-parse" "--show-toplevel"))
  (let ((process-environment (magit-process-environment)) (default-process-coding-system (magit--process-coding-system))) (apply #'process-file process infile buffer display args))
  magit-process-file("C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe" nil (t nil) nil "--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" "-c" "log.showSignature=false" "-c" "color.ui=false" "-c" "color.diff=false" "-c" "i18n.logOutputEncoding=UTF-8" "rev-parse" "--show-toplevel")
  apply(magit-process-file "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe" nil (t nil) nil ("--no-pager" "--literal-pathspecs" "-c" "core.preloadindex=true" "-c" "log.showSignature=false" "-c" "color.ui=false" "-c" "color.diff=false" "-c" "i18n.logOutputEncoding=UTF-8" "rev-parse" "--show-toplevel"))
  magit-process-git((t nil) ("rev-parse" "--show-toplevel"))
  magit-git-str("rev-parse" "--show-toplevel")
  apply(magit-git-str "rev-parse" "--show-toplevel")
  magit-rev-parse-safe("--show-toplevel")
  magit-toplevel()
  (and buffer-file-name (file-readable-p buffer-file-name) (or (< emacs-major-version 27) (with-no-warnings (condition-case nil (executable-find magit-git-executable t) (wrong-number-of-arguments t)))) (magit-toplevel) (or (not magit-auto-revert-tracked-only) (magit-file-tracked-p buffer-file-name)) (not auto-revert-mode) (not global-auto-revert-mode))
  (if (and buffer-file-name (file-readable-p buffer-file-name) (or (< emacs-major-version 27) (with-no-warnings (condition-case nil (executable-find magit-git-executable t) (wrong-number-of-arguments t)))) (magit-toplevel) (or (not magit-auto-revert-tracked-only) (magit-file-tracked-p buffer-file-name)) (not auto-revert-mode) (not global-auto-revert-mode)) (progn (auto-revert-mode 1)))
  (if file (let ((it (find-buffer-visiting file))) (if it (progn (save-current-buffer (set-buffer it) (magit-turn-on-auto-revert-mode-if-desired))))) (if (and buffer-file-name (file-readable-p buffer-file-name) (or (< emacs-major-version 27) (with-no-warnings (condition-case nil (executable-find magit-git-executable t) (wrong-number-of-arguments t)))) (magit-toplevel) (or (not magit-auto-revert-tracked-only) (magit-file-tracked-p buffer-file-name)) (not auto-revert-mode) (not global-auto-revert-mode)) (progn (auto-revert-mode 1))))
  magit-turn-on-auto-revert-mode-if-desired()
  (if auto-revert-mode (progn (auto-revert-mode -1) (magit-turn-on-auto-revert-mode-if-desired)) (magit-turn-on-auto-revert-mode-if-desired))
  (if (eq auto-revert-mode-major-mode major-mode) nil (if auto-revert-mode (progn (auto-revert-mode -1) (magit-turn-on-auto-revert-mode-if-desired)) (magit-turn-on-auto-revert-mode-if-desired)))
  (if auto-revert-mode-set-explicitly nil (if (eq auto-revert-mode-major-mode major-mode) nil (if auto-revert-mode (progn (auto-revert-mode -1) (magit-turn-on-auto-revert-mode-if-desired)) (magit-turn-on-auto-revert-mode-if-desired))))
  (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buf) (if auto-revert-mode-set-explicitly nil (if (eq auto-revert-mode-major-mode major-mode) nil (if auto-revert-mode (progn (auto-revert-mode -1) (magit-turn-on-auto-revert-mode-if-desired)) (magit-turn-on-auto-revert-mode-if-desired)))) (setq auto-revert-mode-major-mode major-mode))
  (progn (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buf) (if auto-revert-mode-set-explicitly nil (if (eq auto-revert-mode-major-mode major-mode) nil (if auto-revert-mode (progn (auto-revert-mode -1) (magit-turn-on-auto-revert-mode-if-desired)) (magit-turn-on-auto-revert-mode-if-desired)))) (setq auto-revert-mode-major-mode major-mode)))
  (if (buffer-live-p buf) (progn (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buf) (if auto-revert-mode-set-explicitly nil (if (eq auto-revert-mode-major-mode major-mode) nil (if auto-revert-mode (progn (auto-revert-mode -1) (magit-turn-on-auto-revert-mode-if-desired)) (magit-turn-on-auto-revert-mode-if-desired)))) (setq auto-revert-mode-major-mode major-mode))))
  (let ((buf (car tail))) (if (buffer-live-p buf) (progn (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buf) (if auto-revert-mode-set-explicitly nil (if (eq auto-revert-mode-major-mode major-mode) nil (if auto-revert-mode (progn ... ...) (magit-turn-on-auto-revert-mode-if-desired)))) (setq auto-revert-mode-major-mode major-mode)))) (setq tail (cdr tail)))
  (while tail (let ((buf (car tail))) (if (buffer-live-p buf) (progn (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buf) (if auto-revert-mode-set-explicitly nil (if (eq auto-revert-mode-major-mode major-mode) nil (if auto-revert-mode ... ...))) (setq auto-revert-mode-major-mode major-mode)))) (setq tail (cdr tail))))
  (let ((tail buffers)) (while tail (let ((buf (car tail))) (if (buffer-live-p buf) (progn (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buf) (if auto-revert-mode-set-explicitly nil (if ... nil ...)) (setq auto-revert-mode-major-mode major-mode)))) (setq tail (cdr tail)))))
  (let ((buffers magit-auto-revert-mode-buffers)) (setq magit-auto-revert-mode-buffers nil) (let ((tail buffers)) (while tail (let ((buf (car tail))) (if (buffer-live-p buf) (progn (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buf) (if auto-revert-mode-set-explicitly nil ...) (setq auto-revert-mode-major-mode major-mode)))) (setq tail (cdr tail))))))
  magit-auto-revert-mode-enable-in-buffers()
  run-hooks(change-major-mode-after-body-hook after-change-major-mode-hook)
  normal-mode(t)
  after-find-file(nil t)
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer Test.html> "c:/Users/rober/..." nil nil "c:/Users/rober/..." (562949953832016 311952014))
  find-file-noselect("c:/Users/rober/..." nil nil nil)
  find-file("c:/Users/rober/...")
  dired--find-file(find-file "c:/Users/rober/...")
  dired--find-possibly-alternative-file("c:/Users/rober/...")
  dired-find-file()
  funcall-interactively(dired-find-file)
  command-execute(dired-find-file)
```

Answer (score 1):

*(Cannot comment because my repuation is less.  So, I will answer instead)*

Do

```
M-x customize-variable RET magit-auto-revert-mode RET
```

and make its value OFF (`nil`).

If you do the above customization, you will be able to open files without `magit` getting  in the way.

Make sure you can run

```
"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe" --version
```

at the command prompt.  Do you see any issues?

---

From [Magit on Windows: Cygwin git vs. Git for Windows : r/emacs](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/8drglj/magit_on_windows_cygwin_git_vs_git_for_windows/)

> Unless you're running `cygwin Emacs`, I would suggest `Git for Windows`.
>
> It would *probably* work with cygwin git too, at least I don't recall any bug reports about it since [#2284](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2284). **According to [some comments in #1318](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1318#issuecomment-109546395) you may have to use `cygwin-mount.el` and/or `setup-cygwin.el`.**
>
> ---
>
> You should consider using `Cygwin Git` (and then `Cygwin Emacs`) if you need to work a lot with Git repositories that include symlinks. Symlinks are a PITA on Windows because creating them requires privilege elevation and will therefore pop up UAC prompts. So Git for Windows by default leaves symlinks disabled. I think the Cygwin Git will support that in a less annoying way, but if this is your use case, I suggest to verify that first.
>
> Another consideration is whether you need python-based Git commands (not included in Git for Windows).

Based on [Magit on windows no longer works with Cygwin Git ·
Issue #1318 · magit/magit](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/1318#issuecomment-109546395)

Try this

1. Download [`cygwin-mount.el`](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/cygwin-mount.el)
2. Download [`setup-cygwin.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/setup-cygwin.el)
3. In your `init.el` (or `.emacs`),add the following

```lisp
(add-to-list 'load-path "where you placed cygwin-mount.el and setup-cygwin.el")
(require 'setup-cygwin)
```

See also https://github.com/benquike/emacs.d/commit/a003f33ede51f4a87b115f5dd8b5bf3e503ed14d

Comment: I can run that at command prompt, and it says: "git version 2.43.0.windows.1". Turning of the magit function could be a good workaround, but I'd also like to fix the underlying issue. There is nothing wrong with my `git` executable, so I wonder what the problem is.

Comment: Revised my earlier commit with some possible solution ... To get a good lead, I suggest searching for  [`is:issue cygwin label:"bug windows" ` in the `magit` issues page](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues?q=is%3Aissue+cygwin+label%3A%22bug+windows%22)

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm don't have cygwin, and I've been using Git for Windows, not a cygwin git. Are you saying I should install cygwin? Those issues seem to be saying Git for Windows is better. No?

Comment: You are using `Cygwin Emacs` right?  Your other question makes it clear that you are using `Cygwin Emacs`.

Comment: I don't think I am. I downloaded GNU Emacs for Windows. In my other question I was asking if I was also supposed to install Cygwin as well, because Emacs commands like `find-name-dired` don't work.

Comment: The `Spawning error ...` you mention, seems to happen more with `Cygwin Emacs`.  Never mind ... Try using [The Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://old.reddit.com/r/planetemacs/search?q=wsl&restrict_sr=on) or this one https://github.com/hubisan/emacs-wsl and take help from [Chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/Emacs).  Also look at [G.4 Emulation of ls on MS-Windows](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/emacs/ls-in-Lisp) and [11.3 EZWinPorts](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/EZWinPorts.html)